# Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.5.RELEASE from/to nexus

Tags: spring-boot, nexus

In my pom.xml, by using the following code, this error comes:

"Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for eu.hermes.sbprojects:sb-firstproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.5.RELEASE from/to nexus
https://nexus.myCompanyNexus.de/repository/maven-group/): nexus.myCompanyNexus.de and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM"

I guess it is proxy problem. But what confusing is, i am at the moment not in office but at home and use my normal wlan at home. As i use Spring Tool Suite as IDE, so i go to Window->Preferences->Network connections.

And set active provider of network connections from Native to Manual.

However, the error is still there. 
And i just change the version from the newest 2.1.5 RELEASE to 2.1.0 RELEASE, and it works.

But i do not understand at all, why?
Why i am still at home, it tolds me Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.5.RELEASE from/to of my company?
Why by using a lower version instead of the newest version, it can work?

Thank you!

Regards,
Zi

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```